# Changing Unsubscribe reason through SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I noticed that you can unsubscribe a user [through SSJS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_listSubscribersUnsubscribe.htm), is it possible to use SSJS to change the unsubscribe reason?

I notice that doing it through [the API seems to be popular](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_unsubLogUnsubEvent.htm)? why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using WSPRoxy:

```
  /* Declare WSProxy */
  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

  var props = [
    {Name:"SubscriberKey", Value:SubscriberKey},
    {Name:"JobID", Value:JobID},
    {Name:"ListID", Value:Listid},
    {Name:"BatchID", Value:BatchID},
    {Name:"Reason", Value:"Consent Centre Unsubscribe"},
  ];
  var data = prox.execute(props, "LogUnsubEvent");
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm relatively new to SSJS in Marketing Cloud, how should I adjust the  code? Taking into account the use-case, do I need to replace just the Listid with the actual value and then run in as Script Activity in Automation Studio? Also, do I need to import those opt-outs from DE to a list first before executing your code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, unsubscribe reason is only insertable with an unsubscribe event. See the following only has retrieve: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubevent.htm

The last unsubscribe event/reason is described in the All Subs list so if you want to replace you could just resubmit an unsubscribe event using ssjs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm

Answer (score 0):

FYI this also seems to have worked:

```js
    var key = Attribute.GetValue('_subscriberkey');
    var email = Attribute.GetValue('emailaddr');
    var jobId = Attribute.GetValue('jobid');
    var batchId = Attribute.GetValue('_JobSubscriberBatchID');
    var listId = Attribute.GetValue('listid');;

    Write("\nSSJS Unsubscribe Status:\n");
    var lists = List.Retrieve({Property: "ID", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: listId});
    var list = List.Init(lists[0].CustomerKey);
    var status = list.Subscribers.Upsert(email, {"Status" : "Unsubscribed", "Reason" : "Hello World")
```